# How to run php page using cron in Bitrix24

Tags: cron, bitrix

I have index.php file in home/bitrix/www/services/report/.
Now I want to run this file in every 1 min, how I can set a cron in Bitrix24.
I tried the below code but its not working.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /home/bitrix/www/services/report/index.php
```

when I run this code through command line then I get following error.

Failed opening required '/home/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php.

Answer (score 0):

Check you page, probably it starts with something like this:

`require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");`

$_SERVER global variable is set up by web server. So `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` does not exists (or set up with incorrect value), when you run script in CLI.
You need to set it manually to your document root.

Here is an example:

`$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] = '/home/bitrix/www';`

You could replace `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` substring in require expressions, but as I remember `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` is used all over the core files and maybe setting it up will be best option.

**UPDATE:**
Another option could be running **wget** or **curl** to your url from **cron**